# Elements wont function in Chrome binary driver on a specific page

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

A specific page in the site I am testing have few buttons that wont register any clicks via selenium Webdriver or manual clicks while opened with chrome binary driver. It works fine while I manually test it in chrome browser.

I tried adding waits, javascript click, action click for selenium with no success.

Webdriver is not throwing an error for clicking/finding element as its doing as it supposed to (I think) but since the page is not responding and not moving forward to the next, I am getting a page object error

Answer (score 0):

Hard to help without specific details, but here's my best attempt:

Potential Problem 1. Make sure the element is not on an iframe, if so here's a link explaning how to fix your code:
[How to switch frames - Selenium - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879206/how-to-switch-between-frames-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Potential Problem 2. Open an incognito/alternate tab, access the same page and check that the CSS Selector/X-Path you are using is existent and pointing to the correct element. If that is not the case, try to correct it by looking at the classes that did not change from the previous Selector to the new.

Comment: Thank you for your input I have edited the question a bit hope it helps. There is no iframe in the page. The issue is few elements in that page (different places in the page) wont response even if i click it manually when its open via chrome binary driver. PS: the page still being developed and I am working in dev environment not UAT.

Comment: Those same elements works perfectly in chrome browser manually but if opened via chrome binary Webdriver they wont function neither with selenium or manual clicks

Comment: @Azfar I don't really know what might be causing the issue but since this seems to be a chrome specific problem, I've made an edit suggestion to your question to add the tag 'selenium-chromedriver'. I also suggest that you add specifics such as chrome's webdriver version to your question.

Comment: @Azfar This is the closest to what I've seen that is similar to what you are describing: [Selenium Click not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55218443/selenium-click-not-working-chrome-driver-version-73-0-3683-68)